# Pick a matrix cell according to its probability

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, random, probability

I have a 2D matrix of positive real values, stored as follow:

```
vector<vector<double>> matrix;
```

Each cell can have a value equal or greater to 0, and this value represents the possibility of the cell to be chosen. In particular, for example, a cell with a value equals to 3 has three times the probability to be chosen compared to a cell with value 1.

I need to select `N` cells of the matrix (0 <= `N` <= total number of cells) randomly, but according to their probability to be selected.

How can I do that?

The algorithm should be as fast as possible.

Comment: std::discrete_distribution is tailor made for this situation.

Comment: @user515430 In which way?

Comment: @Nick if you consider your matrix as a single dimension array you could directly use [discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) (+1 to @user515430)

Comment: @fjardon Can you show me how?

Comment: @Nick on second thought it won't solve your issue because you want a sampling without replacement and the discrete_distribution has a fixed probability for each item. So on the second draw you could get the item returned on the first draw.

Comment: @fjardon: I assumed that he wanted sampling with replacement, otherwise my methods are broken also. If it's without replacement then the problem might not be possible for some matrices and some values of `N` so I guess OP should clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

I describe two methods, A and B.

A works in time approximately `N * number of cells`, and uses space `O(log number of cells)`. It is good when `N` is small.

B works in time approximately `(number of cells + N) * O(log number of cells)`, and uses space `O(number of cells)`. So, it is good when `N` is large (or even, 'medium') but uses a lot more memory, in practice it might be slower in some regimes for that reason.

---

Method A:

The first thing you need to do is normalize the entries. (It's not clear to me if you assume they are normalized or not.) That means, sum all the entries and divide by the sum. (This part is potentially slow, so it's better if you assume or require that it already happened.)

Then you sample like this:

1. Choose a random `[i,j]` entry of the matrix (by choosing `i,j` each uniformly randomly from the range of integers `0` to `n-1`).
2. Choose a uniformly random real number `p` in the range `[0, 1]`.
3. Check if `matrix[i][j] > p`. If so, return the pair `[i][j]`. If not, go back to step 1.

Why does this work? The probability that we end at step 3 with any particular output, is equal to, the probability that `[i][j]` was selected (this is the same for each entry), times the probality that the number `p` was small enough. This is proportional to the value `matrix[i][j]`, so the sampling is choosing each entry with the correct proportions. It's also possible that at step 3 we go back to the start -- does that bias things? Basically, no. The reason is, suppose we arbitrarily choose a number `k` and then consider the distribution of the algorithm, conditioned on stopping exactly after `k` rounds. Conditioned on the assumption that we stop at the `k`'th round, no matter what value `k` we choose, the distribution we sample has to be exactly right by the above argument. Since if we eliminate the case that `p` is too small, the other possibilities all have their proportions correct. Since the distribution is perfect for each value of `k` that we might condition on, and the overall distribution (not conditioned on `k`) is an average of the distributions for each value of `k`, the overall distribution is perfect also.

If you want to analyze the number of rounds that typically needed in a rigorous way, you can do it by analyzing the probability that we actually stop at step 3 for any particular round. Since the rounds are independent, this is the same for every round, and statistically, it means that the running time of the algorithm is poisson distributed. That means it is tightly concentrated around its mean, and we can determine the mean by knowing that probability.

The probability that we stop at step 3 can be determined by considering the conditional probability that we stop at step 3, given that we chose any particular entry `[i][j]`. By the formulas for conditional expectation, you get that

```
Pr[ stop at step 3 ] = sum_{i,j} ( 1/(n^2) * Matrix[i,j] )
```

Since we assumed the matrix is normalized, this sum reduces to just `1/n^2`. So, the expected number of rounds is about `n^2` (that is, `n^2` up to a constant factor) no matter what the entries in the matrix are. You can't hope to do a lot better than that I think -- that's about the same amount of time it takes to just read all the entries of the matrix, and it's hard to sample from a distribution that you cannot even read all of.

Note: What I described is a way to correctly sample a single element -- to get `N` elements from one matrix, you can just repeat it `N` times.

---

Method B:

Basically you just want to compute a histogram and sample inversely from it, so that you know you get exactly the right distribution. Computing the histogram is expensive, but once you have it, getting samples is cheap and easy.

In C++ it might look like this:

```
// Make histogram
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef std::pair<uint, uint> upair;
typedef std::map<double, upair> histogram_type;
histogram_type histogram;
double cumulative = 0.0f;
for (uint i = 0; i < Matrix.size(); ++i) {
  for (uint j = 0; j < Matrix[i].size(); ++j) {
    cumulative += Matrix[i][j];
    histogram[cumulative] = std::make_pair(i,j);
  }
}

std::vector<upair> result;
for (uint k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
  // Do a sample (this should never repeat... if it does not find a lower bound you could also assert false quite reasonably since it means something is wrong with rand() implementation)
  while(1) {
    double p = cumulative * rand(); // Or, for best results use std::mt19937 or boost::mt19937 and sample a real in the range [0,1] here.
    histogram_type::iterator it = histogram::lower_bound(p);
    if (it != histogram.end()) {
      result.push_back(it->second);
      break;
    }
  }
}
return result;
```

Here the time to make the histogram is something like `number of cells * O(log number of cells)` since inserting into the map takes time `O(log n)`. You need an ordered data structure in order to get cheap lookup `N * O(log number of cells)` later when you do repeated sampling. Possibly you could choose a more specialized data structure to go faster, but I think there's only limited room for improvement.

Edit: As @Bob__ points out in comments, in method (B) a written there is potentially going to be some error due to floating point round-off if the matrices are quite large, even using type `double`, at this line:

```
cumulative += Matrix[i][j];
```

The problem is that, if `cumulative` is much larger than `Matrix[i][j]` beyond what the floating point precision can handle then these each time this statement is executed you may observe significant errors which accumulate to introduce significant inaccuracy.

As he suggests, if that happens, the most straightforward way to fix it is to sort the values `Matrix[i][j]` first. You could even do this in the general implementation to be safe -- sorting these guys isn't going to take more time asymptotically than you already have anyways.

Comment: I think you don't have to normalize the matrix. Once you have calculated the sum, in your point 2 just chose a random number in [0,sum/n^2].

Comment: @Bob__: yeah I mean, I guess that's the same as normalizing, you are just multiplying `p` instead of dividing by the sum. It might be marginally faster since you don't have to do `n^2` divisions but it won't be asymptotically faster since you still have to get the sum.

Comment: Your B method is what I was thinking. Maybe you can optimize it by sorting the N samples before looking up. My only concerne is numerical instability of summing the potentialy small matrix[i][j] to the increasingly big cumulative, even using double.

Comment: I tried your A method but it does not work for me. The matrix is huge, and the values of the cells are small (most of them are smaller than 10). This means that when I normalize the weights I obtain a big value for the sum a small values for the new weights. Therefore, when I pick the probability p [0, 1] the number is (almost always) grater than the normalized weight. This approach takes hours to terminate.

Comment: @Nick: How large is your matrix exactly? Can you tolerate error / defect in the distribution that you sample? Sampling perfectly from an arbitrary distribution with a huge support is inherently complex. If you can make more assumptions about your matrix there might be a better approach but given what you've posted in the question I don't know what else you can do. You can try using `std::discrete_distribution` like the other guy posted, but I looked at what that does, I don't think it's significantly different from `B`.

Comment: @ChrisBeck An average of 1 million elements (1000x1000). I can tollerate small defects in the distribution.

Comment: @Chris Beck: As a partial strategy for containing the round-off errors in method B for large matrices, have you considered using an extra vector to store the partial sum of each row, reset the cumulative before starting next row calculation and use this vector as a nested "histogram" to speed up the look-up fase (first find the row, then the column)?